# Dynamic where clause with set number of columns

Tags: sql

I am bringing in arguments from an arbitrary source and there may be 1,2 or 3 args passed that need to go as a where clause in an sql query.

How can I write this query so no matter what args are passed the query will run with as many args as it can. I was thinking:

```
Passed in: x=1,y=null,z=5

//Do some simple checks and assign local variables when the value are not null.

if(arg == null) 
{
arg = (/*some wild card that allows any value to be returned*/)
}
else{
arg = arg
}
```

Generated clause: WHERE X=localx AND Y=(ANY VALUE) AND Z=localz

What can I use for Y in this example so I can avoid dynamically creating a string with a variable amount of args? I found myself having a really hard time trying to articulate this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to assume SQL Server. Use the ISNULL command and make all incoming parameters null when not provided.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE ISNULL(@Param1,Field1)=Field1
AND ISNULL(@Param2,Field2)=Field2
AND ISNULL(@Param3,Field3)=Field3
AND ISNULL(@Param4,Field4)=Field4
AND ISNULL(@Param5,Field5)=Field5
```

Answer (score 3):

A better solution, if any of the fields might have NULL values is:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE (@Param1 is null or @Param1 = Field1) and
      (@Param2 is null or @Param2 = Field2) and
      (@Param3 is null or @Param3 = Field3) and
      (@Param4 is null or @Param4 = Field4) and
      (@Param5 is null or @Param5 = Field5)
```

The main difference between this and the solution that uses `isnull` is that this version handles NULL values in the fields.  The expression `isnull(@param1, field1) = field1` returns false when @param1 is NULL and field1 is NULL.  The expression `@Param1 is null or @Param1 = Field1` returns true when both are NULL.